# WARNING: terminal is not fully functional despite xterm-color

Tags: unity, virtualbox, gnome-terminal, git, xterm

I have two Ubuntu VMs. On one of them, whenever I run `git diff` or `git log`, I see:

`WARNING: terminal is not fully functional`

I then get a horrible, monocolour diff (yech).

How do I fix this? I already tried:

- Setting `TERM` to `xterm-color`, `ansi`, and yes, even `msys` (all to no avail)
- Restarting my machine
- Checking that `TERM` is set to something sane (`xterm` by default)

I ended up editing `~/.bashrc` to set `TERM` to `xterm-color`, which makes my terminal prompts look MOAR awesome, but doesn't solve this one problem with Git.

Comment: What do you have in `~/.gitconfig`? What is your pager (`$PAGER` or `/etc/alternatives/pager`)?

Comment: @Gilles `~/.gitconfig` just has my user and password; `$PAGER` is empty and `/etc/alternatives/pager` looks like some binary data I can't make any sense of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved itself. I think it was multiple reboots (host and guest) that finally got it to work.